# Converting html to pdf in php?

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation, html2pdf

I know that there is a lot of posts about this problem.But can someone help me to setup this http://www.rustyparts.com/pdf.php script to work on my localhost.I just spent all week on this problem.I have download imagemagic,ghostscript,activeperl,...,everything,but still can't make simple example to work.

Comment: That's sort of a no-longer maintained library.. its last release is from 2006! I would consider a newer -and active- one.

Comment: If you decide not to continue with the library you are currently using you can find a good list here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3178448/264628. Looks like you're trying out wkhtmltopdf, but there are a number of pure PHP solutions out there as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) via a system call. See [How to install wkhtmltopdf on a linux based (shared hosting) web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273534/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-on-a-linux-based-web-server) for installation help.

> wkhtmltopdf is a command line program
>   which permits to create a pdf from an
>   url, a local html  file or stdin. It
>   produces a pdf like rendred with the
>   WebKit engine.

See the sample from this page [here](http://marco.uctleg.net/resources/sample.pdf).

php code tested on Ubuntu (you'll need to change the `/tmp/` to a temporary directory on Windows):

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com';
$pdffile = tempnam('/tmp/', 'wkhtmltopdf_');
$handle = popen("wkhtmltopdf $url $pdffile 2>&1", "r");
while (!feof($handle)) 
  fread($handle, 4096);
pclose($handle);
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
$file = fopen($pdffile, "r");
while(!feof($file))
  print fread($file, 4096);
unlink($pdffile);
```

There are also [php bindings](https://github.com/mreiferson/php-wkhtmltox) which removes the need to use a system call yourself, which is a simpler (and safer!) option.

```
try {
    $wkhtmltopdf = new Core_Wkhtmltopdf(array('path' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/uploads/'));
    $wkhtmltopdf->setTitle("Title");
    $wkhtmltopdf->setHtml("Content");
    $wkhtmltopdf->output(Wkhtmltopdf::MODE_DOWNLOAD, "file.pdf");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Ohhh,another php pdf library :((( but I need to create system for exporting html pages to pdf,user to click on link on website,and than pdf file is generated ?

Comment: Be careful with the single quotes there. If you want variables substitution, those will have to be double quotes.

Comment: ok,cool,it looks great,can I use this library on my website,I'm not php guru,I'm just learning some stuff

Comment: @ncuesta Fixed. @user This isn't a library at all, it's a standalone binary you can call from within PHP via a system call as I've shown. Many html2pdf's out there use there own rendering engine, this one uses the excellent WebKit engine used in Chrome, Safari and other major browsers.

Comment: I didn't play with system calls with php so I don't know how to use that,is it simple to install on localhost,first will check this one http://html2pdf.fr/en/default

Comment: @user [Download the appropriate release](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list) and give it a try on the command line first. I also found php bindings (see edit in answer).

Comment: @marcog, does HTML needs to be valid? No that it is problem, just asking.

Comment: @Webarto It uses webkit, so it does a great job: [invalid html](http://marco.uctleg.net/resources/invalid.html) and [resulting pdf](http://marco.uctleg.net/resources/invalid.pdf)

Comment: Yeah I thought so. Very nice project. Thanks for example.

Comment: so how to install this on localhost for testing ?

Comment: @user I already gave a download link above. Try show some effort. :)

Comment: sorry,I just spent all week on this :S I have downloaded wkhtmltox-0.10.0_rc1-installer.exe and from github https://github.com/mreiferson/php-wkhtmltox this,just now need to connect all this,...,how to do this? sorry,I'm not php guru

Comment: I installed first thing,is there some simple tutorial for beginers?

Comment: oooo,c-rap,I will not sleap another night :(( to make this thing work without command line

Comment: @user You do not need the command line. Use the sample code I provided in my answer.

Comment: Ok,can you help me a little bit more with this,I have setup on my localhost test.php,and copy your code,of course that will not work,what I need to include in my test.php file.

Comment: just copy this : try {
    $wkhtmltopdf = new Core_Wkhtmltopdf(array('path' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/uploads/'));
    $wkhtmltopdf->setTitle("Title");
    $wkhtmltopdf->setHtml("Content");
    $wkhtmltopdf->output(Wkhtmltopdf::MODE_DOWNLOAD, "file.pdf");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

Comment: APPLICATION_PATH - this should be path to my wkt instalation on my hard ? in c://program files... ?

Comment: @user I've included some code which I've tested and it works on Ubuntu. You'll need to change `/tmp/` as I mention in my answer to make it work on windows. It's late here, and I'm sleepy. Hopefully I wake up to see you've solved it painlessly. :)

Comment: I have made this works with command line,just to make this works in php script,ok,thank you for your time :) I will give it a try couple more times.

Comment: No,it doesn't work for me on windows your code.I change temp folder name to C:\\Windows\Temp,c-rap :((

Comment: It looks really great when convert html page from command line

Comment: questuion,where is that page saved ? that pdf file,where is saved ?

Comment: @user `tempnam` generates a random filename beginning with `C:\\Windows\Temp\wkhtmltopdf_`. The file is saved there, but then the `unlink` deletes it. Change `$pdffile` to something static and comment out the `unlink` if you want to test it.

Comment: Yeah,that was the problem,file is created but not displayed in a browser.It works great,except part displaying in a browser.

Comment: @user Try change `while(!feof($file)) print fread($file, 4096);` to `print file_get_contents($file);`

Comment: no,that,didn't fix anything.Don't worry,it is ok,will find solution for that :)) tnx for your help.

Comment: tnx mate,tnx for helping me :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple but powerful: http://html2pdf.fr/en/default

```
$html = file_get_contents("valid.html");
require_once("html2pdf.class.php");
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF("P", "A4", "en", array(10, 10, 10, 10));
$html2pdf->setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$html2pdf->Output("pdf/PDF.pdf", "F"); //output to file
$html2pdf->Output(); //output to browser
```

Comment: this looks great,is it simple to install on localhost ? then later on server ?

Comment: Yes just extract it in root folder and you are all set.

Comment: Cool,I will take a look,at this,tnx mate :)

Comment: I get this : preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpt\html2pdf\html2pdf.class.php on line 970

Comment: Probably your HTML is not valid, you must keep it valid in order to successfully convert it, check on this site: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: it is valid,now it just give me blank page,I use this code :     $url = "http://localhost/cpt/?cat=4";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5; // set to zero for no timeout
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
    $content = $file_contents;
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->Output('this_shit.pdf');

Comment: Don't cURL yourself :) Use file_get_contents. Try this path http://127.0.0.1/cpt/?cat=4 , if still no luck echo $content and see if it contains HTML.

Answer (score 1):

[DocRaptor.com](http://docraptor.com) is a good option - it uses Prince XML, so the quality is better than other tools, and it's a web app, so nothing to download. It also works in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is another library that generates PDF files: [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). Nice and quite simple. You can find many examples around.