# How to install the wkhtmltopdf shell utility?

Tags: php, installation, wkhtmltopdf, whm

I have a dedicated WHM / cPanel server with root access.

I am trying to install a shell utility (wkhtmltopdf) to /usr/local/bin/ so that I can call it from within php using exec.

I've got a handle on the php stuff.  But I am completely new to all server / sys admin related things.

I have checked out the instructions on http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ - but these assume a higher level of knowledge than I currently have.

I am wondering if anyone can help explain, to a complete newbie, how to go about installing wkhtmltopdf.

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on your server and system. Do you have root/sudo access? Is it an ubuntu?

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

Installed it for me nicely and then you can do symbolic links to point to the executable, but this all depends on the environment. This is kind of a broad question, I'll edit the answer if you want more info but it's hard to write such a generic answer that it would work in any case :) Also perhaps check out [How to install wkhtmltopdf on a linux based (shared hosting) web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273534/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-on-a-linux-based-web-server)