# Installation of wkhtmltopdf static binary in Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Tags: php, installation, wkhtmltopdf

Can anyone tell me, how to install **wkhtmltopdf** static binary in Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit? Also which version of **wkhtmltopdf** will be a suitable one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install wkhtmltopdf on a linux based web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273534/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-on-a-linux-based-web-server)

Comment: Yeah, same as that one, but I want to know, which version of wkhtmltopdf will be perfect one. Because, I'm getting lot of problems while generating PDF from the HTML content which are really good. Letter spacing issue, Page width issue etc.

Comment: There is no perfect wkhtmltopdf and what you want depends on your situation. That question cannot really be answered so generically. I would go with the newest stable one (as with any software).

Comment: Ok Nenotlep, but am also using stable versions only :) Cool, let me deal it :)

Answer (score 2):

The best version to use would be the [latest one (0.12.0)](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/latest) -- 64-bit builds should be available in a day's time.

Disclaimer: I'm the co-maintainer for the project -- any bug-reports with this version would be welcome.