# How to install wkhtmltopdf 0.12.0 and later on a linux based web server?

Tags: php, linux, wkhtmltopdf, shared-hosting

[**wkhtmltopdf**](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) 0.11.0 *and earlier* install simply copying [**linux static binary file**](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2) to web server as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3116571/2464199

and run it via PHP command like

`exec('/path/to/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 file.html file.php');`

In **newer** versions wkhtmltopdf (0.12.0 *and later*) **no** static binary file.

How can I install it now on shared hosting account without root access?

*OS on web server:*

> Linux multidomain1.hostsila.com 2.6.18-274.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jul 22 04:43:29 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> Linux version 2.6.18-274.el5 (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)) #1 SMP Fri Jul 22 04:43:29 EDT 2011
>
> CentOS release 5.10 (Final)

Comment: They do provide static binaries -> http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: @YuruiRayZhang What? Where?

Comment: in that download page, download a centos 5.10 build, extract it, the static build is under a bin folder or somewhere in there(i don't remember the exact location.

Comment: @YuruiRayZhang See the first answer. This has been done. But the static binary has an error when running.

Comment: hm...maybe you should try to build it yourself and submit a ticket in their github repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see the official binaries for 0.12.1, they are actually RPMs. If you do not have root access on the server, you can simply run the following command to extract the RPM contents:

`rpm2cpio wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-centos5-amd64.rpm | cpio -idmv`

You should get the binaries in the `usr/local/bin` subfolder, which you can then copy to any location that you want.

Please note that you may need to ask the host to install the dependent packages (`fontconfig freetype libpng zlib libjpeg openssl libX11 libXext libXrender libstdc++ glibc`) if they are not already installed.

Comment: Thanks for the command! Static binary file is done. But wkhtmltopdf has an error when running: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Version 0.11.0 and 0.10.0 working without errors.

Comment: Do you get the crash on any input or on some files only?

Comment: On almost all files. On the rest files I get this error `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'`

Comment: Can you see if the binaries work for you in a VM if you have root access? I suspect that it is something to do with your web server which has enabled some security settings which cause a crash in `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: I have no possibility to do this. Thank you anyway. Already, it is not necessary. I use the earlier version which works fine.