# Not able to use wkhtmltopdf in containerized AWS lambda

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have to make a pdf out of some html pages in a containerized lambda. For this purpose I am trying to use pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf. I am not able to use it an d receiving the error as shown in picture-[image]

**Error text-**

No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "./wkhtmltopdf"

If this file exists please check that this process can read it or you can pass path to it manually in method call, check README. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf

**My lambda code:-**

```
 import pdfkit as pdf
 def lambda_function:
    config = pdf.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='./wkhtmltopdf')
    pdf.from_file(
        filelist_new,
        output_filename,
        options={
            'margin-top': '0.2in',
            'margin-right': '0.2in',
            'margin-bottom': '0.4in',
            'margin-left': '0.2in',
            'orientation': 'Landscape',
            'page-size': 'A4',
            'encoding': 'UTF-8',
            'footer-line': '',
            'footer-spacing': 1,
            'footer-font-name': 'Times,serif',
            'footer-font-size': '10'
            },
        configuration=config,
        )
```

**My docker file-**

```
FROM umihico/aws-lambda-selenium-python:latest
RUN pip install pdfkit
RUN pip install boto3
RUN pip install wkhtmltopdf --target "./"
COPY lambda_function.py ./
CMD [ "lambda_function.lambda_handler" ]
```

and this is when I tried to find wkhtmlpdf by running the docker container:-
[image]

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I tried what you mentioned but I am still receiving the same error- No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "./"

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I tried but I am still getting `No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "/var/task/wkhtmltopdf"`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary My issue got solved(updated in answer). Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: Issue got solved**

This worked for my case.

**DockerFile:**

```
FROM umihico/aws-lambda-selenium-python:latest
RUN pip install pdfkit --target ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN pip install boto3
RUN yum install -y openssl xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
RUN curl "https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox-0.12.6-1.amazonlinux2.x86_64.rpm" -L -o wkhtmltox-0.12.6-1.amazonlinux2.x86_64.rpm
RUN rpm -i wkhtmltox-0.12.6-1.amazonlinux2.x86_64.rpm
COPY lambda_function.py ./
CMD [ "lambda_function.lambda_handler" ]
```

Lambda code:

```
import pdfkit as pdf


def lambda_function:
    config = pdf.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf')
    pdf.from_file(
        filelist_new,
        output_filename,
        options={
            'enable-local-file-access': '',
            'margin-top': '0.2in',
            'margin-right': '0.2in',
            'margin-bottom': '0.4in',
            'margin-left': '0.2in',
            'orientation': 'Landscape',
            'page-size': 'A4',
            'encoding': 'UTF-8',
            'footer-line': '',
            'footer-spacing': 1,
            'footer-font-name': 'Times,serif',
            'footer-font-size': '10'
            },
        configuration=config,
        )
```

Links which I referred- https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-create-pdf-files-in-python-using-pdfkit/ , [How to install wkhtmltopdf on a linux based (shared hosting) web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273534/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-on-a-linux-based-shared-hosting-web-server)