# Installing wkhtmltopdf to hosting

Tags: ubuntu, debian, wkhtmltopdf, shared-hosting

I want to run my bot on hosting; for the bot to work, I need wkhtmltopdf. **I don't have root and cannot use sudo.**

by command `uname -a`:
`Linux de47dd89-827f-4271-9cad-0cbf6b95d4e6 5.15.0-91-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 14 13:30:08 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

But `cat /etc/os-release`:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I didn’t understand the architecture, so I tried to install **amd** and **arm**, but I don’t have root and cannot install `deb` files... Old versions were published in `.tar.bz2`.

When I do `tar xvjf wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-i386.tar.bz2 mv wkhtmltopdf-i386 /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf` from [How to install wkhtmltopdf on a linux based (shared hosting) web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273534/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-on-a-linux-based-shared-hosting-web-server) I get this:

````
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now```

I installed package, unpacked it on my Windows with Winrar, sent it to the hosting, tried to run: ```./wkhtmltopdf -i386 http://www.example.com example.pdf``` and got an error:
```/bin/sh: 1: ./wkhtmltopdf-i386: Permission denied```

If I overlooked an already existing question with my problem - sorry, I'm at 0:46 am...
And, please, don't swear too much about the design, that's my first question...
````

Comment: If you're using shared hosting you'll need to ask your hosting company if they support the module you want to install.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I asked the hosting, they said that it would work if I gave permissions to this file (I also forgot, the main thing is that I can do it myself), but this doesn’t matter anymore, because in principle wkhtmltopdf won’t work due to unsupported system version

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [unix.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

Answer (score -1):

I managed to unpack the deb package, but wkhtmltopdf requires a certain system library *(Lord, that was two weeks ago, I completely forgot what it was)*
I saw that I cannot download wkhtmltopdf to Debian12, because it does not exist
-_-

Comment: [The package page](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/wkhtmltopdf) tells you exactly what its dependencies are.